# Celery and instance variables

Tags: python, celery

Celery allows to define your own class task so you could split a task into functions and combine those into a class, like:

```
 class MyTask(Task):
      is_abstract = True

      def sub_task1(self):
           pass

      def sub_task2(self, arg1, arg2):
           pass

      def sub_task3(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
           pass

@app.task(base=MyTask, bind=True):
def do_some_stuff(self, pk):
     print('Hello')
     arg1, arg2, arg3 = 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'
     self.sub_task1()
     self.sub_task2(arg1, arg2)
     self.sub_task3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I want to move initialization of `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` variables into a separate function and make them class fields, so there is no need to pass then directly upon a call:

```
 class MyTask(Task):
      ....
      def sub_task3(self):
             self.arg1 ...


def do_some_stuff(self, pk):
     print('Hello')
     self.setup()
     self.sub_task1()
     self.sub_task2()
     self.sub_task3()
```

But as I am aware [celery instantiates](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation) `MyTask` class only once. Does this mean that if a few tasks will run in parallel `self.argX`variables will be overwritten? So the only way to work this arround - introduce another class?

Comment: If the values are to be overwritten,then you shouldn't set them as the instance or class variables. They should be the passed just as arguments to functions like your first approach.

Comment: @Babu unfortunately your solution actually is what I want to avoid. It seems that another class is the only solution.